# A textbox will only be visible if it has some value to show from databse using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a text box visible only if has some value from DB.

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work properly.

```
<input type="text" name="p_name" id="txt1" value="<%=class1.getName()%>" style="display:if(document.getElementById('txt1')!=''){document.getElementById('txt1').style.display='block';}else{document.getElementById('txt1').style.display='none';};">
```

Please help me to solve this problem using JavaScript and HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use Javascript in the style attribute of the input element. Instead, use javascript with a `<script>` tag to run it properly. All you have to do is to determine if the input is empty or not and hide it accordingly.

Two examples, with the same Javascript:

**Input not empty:**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => {
  const txt1 = document.getElementById('txt1');
  txt1.style.display = txt1.value && txt1.value !== '' ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="p_name" id="txt1" value="<%=class1.getName()%>">
```

**Input empty:**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => {
  const txt1 = document.getElementById('txt1');
  txt1.style.display = txt1.value && txt1.value !== '' ? 'block' : 'none';
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="p_name" id="txt1">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script for it using the same conditions as you are currently using and hide the text box by 
`$('#txt1').hide()`
Similarly use `show()` function to show the text box.